# Dead apps still visible on Elementary 7.1 Horus

Tags: elementary-project, vscode

I have a strange issue since i've upgraded to elementary os 7.1:
If an application crashes, it dissapears from the dock (normal), I don't see the process anymore (normal), but it is still displayed...

In the pic I've attached, there are 2 crashed apps:

- vscode (installed directly from a deb)
- insomnia (installed via flatpack)
  Both still have visible windows, but as you can see in the terminal, they don't exist anymore.

Is this a known bug? How can I debug / fix this?

Thank you!

[image]